# set current index of qtableview base on some string

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qlistwidget, qmodelindex

I have a `QTableView` whith a `QSqlqueryModel`

```
QSqlQueryModel db_model_.setQuery("SELECT * FROM Main WHERE Type='1' ORDER BY Count DESC");
tableView.setModel(&db_model_);
```

`Main` defined as :

```
Word(TEXT) | Count(INTEGER) | Type(INTEGER
```

I want to select a row of this table base on the text of item that user selects from another `QListWidget` .

I tried `setCurrentIndex` but it accept a `QModelIndex` . I can't figure out how to search through whole `Word` column of my `tableView`  and find the string of that `listWidget` and feed it to `QModelIndex`

```
void (QListWidget::*itemClicked)(QListWidgetItem*) = &QListWidget::itemClicked;

connect(&listWidget, itemClicked, [&](QListWidgetItem * item){
    const QString& text= item->text();
    //How to search thorough the Word column and find text and select it?!
});
```

Note that I can't use same model for these two widget because the way they fill is completely different .

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [QAbstractItemModel::index](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#index) for iterating through the first column and using `setCurrentIndex` for changing the current selected item.

It works fine now.

```
connect(&listWidget, itemClicked, [&](QListWidgetItem * item){
    const QString& text= item->text();
    int size = tableView.model()->rowCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        QModelIndex& cur=tableView.model()->index(i, 0);
        if (cur.data() == text){
            tableView.setCurrentIndex(cur);
            tableView.scrollTo(cur);
            break;
        }
    }
});
```